# Excel VBA: How do I sort data on one worksheet before creating a chart on a different sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

VBA: I'm trying to populate bar charts on a primary sheet based on data that is contained on a separate sheet. However, I need to get vba to sort the data in descending order before populating the chart.

I have macros to populate league tables on a yearly basis, however, each time I run a macro for a selected year, the bar chart is generated without sorting the data in descending order. When I try to include a code to sort the data, I usually get the run time error 91.

Here is my current code - could someone assist me? This is my first time using vba. Ideally I would like to sort the data in column N before generating the chart. Thanks.

```
Sub NewIssues2014()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim dashboard As Worksheet

Set sht = Worksheets("New Issues League Table")
Set dashboard = Worksheets("Dashboard")
ArrangerLastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
YearLastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("New Issues League Table").Select
Range("M1:S1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("New Issues League Table").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields _
    .Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("New Issues League Table").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields _
    .Add Key:=Range("N1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("New Issues League Table").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

With dashboard
dashboard.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarStacked
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range("L2:L" & ArrangerLastRow & ",N2:N" & YearLastRow), PlotBy:=xlColumns
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Crosses = xlMaximum
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.HasLegend = False
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "2014 New Issue Deals"
End With

With ActiveChart.Parent
.Height = 325
.Width = 900
.Top = 1070
.Left = Range("B94").Left
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: "I usually get the run time error 91" -- please include the code that is throwing this error.

Comment: Hi matt2103, this line appears to be causing the error: 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("New Issues League Table").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields _
        .Clear

Answer (score 0):

Autofilter works great when used directly, but seems to be rather touchy when controlled via VBA.  Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-sort-method-excel

To use a standard sort function, you basically just have to remove "Autofilter" from everything, and be more specific with your range references:

```
Sheets("New Issues League Table").Select
Range("M1:Sx").Select 'Replace x with the last row in your table
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("New Issues League Table").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("New Issues League Table").Sort.SortFields _
    .Add Key:=Range("N1:Nx"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal  'Again, replace x with the last row in your table
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("New Issues League Table").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

EDIT: Replying to comment--
Your `With` statement is a little off.  You open it, but then don't actually use it.  It's also prudent to avoid using the `.Select` function as much as possible--it's not actually needed in most situations. This would be better:

```
dashboard.Shapes.AddChart
With ActiveChart
    .ChartType = xlBarStacked
    .SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range("L2:L" & ArrangerLastRow & ",N2:N" & YearLastRow), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    .Axes(xlCategory).Select
    .Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = True
    .Axes(xlCategory).Crosses = xlMaximum
    .HasTitle = True
    .HasLegend = False
    .ChartTitle.Text = "2014 New Issue Deals"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried your method and the manual sort works. However, I now face the same error with the code for the chart, specifically for the line: ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarStacked. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Nicole See my edit, it works in test runs for me.  Let me know if it also works for you.